# How to limit access to JMX to just a few IP-addresses?

Tags: java

I'm dealing with a vendor-provided application, which has multiple components running on separate computers. The components communicate with each other using (unsecured) JMX -- which means, anybody can access the JMX-port of each component...

I have accessed them thus -- using `jconsole` -- and found various things exposed. The worst attack I can imagine is "merely" of a denial-of-service kind: verbose logging can be turned on remotely. But it may also be, that my imagination is too narrow...

The examples out there show, how to limit JMX-functionality to `localhost` -- but that's not acceptable here, because *some* external access is necessary. How would I limit it to a (small) group of IP-addresses?

We do not have root-access here, which makes the firewall method undesirable -- as it'd require coordination with too many people, unfortunately. If it all possible, we'd like some Java-specific method -- is there one?

I asked this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872698/), but the issue just became pressing again :-)